# Need to grant select permission on View but not in table which is in a different database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in database A and a view using that table in database B. **I want To give `select` privilege to a user on that view but I do not want to give any access to table.**

Can anyone help me on that issue?

Comment: [Srutzky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158609/giving-special-permissions-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server/158610#158610) has made an answer like this before, I'd suggest to give it a read and see if this is a solution to your problem. There are also suggestions there that may help.

Answer (score 1):

I will give a full demo how you can achieve this.
Create 2 database

```
USE [MASTER];
GO
CREATE DATABASE [TestA]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [TestB]
GO
```

Create a login and user in both database.

```
USE [master];
GO
CREATE LOGIN TestUser WITH PASSWORD = 'Password', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GO
```

Create user in both database using the login above.

```
USE TestA
GO
CREATE USER TestUser FROM LOGIN TestUser;
GO
USE TestB
GO
CREATE USER TestUser FROM LOGIN TestUser;
GO
```

Create table is TestA database.

```
CREATE TABLE TestA.dbo.t1(id INT);
GO
```

Create view in TestB database.

```
USE TestB; 
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewA
AS
  SELECT id FROM TestA.dbo.t1;
GO
```

Enabling Cross-database Ownership Chaining

```
ALTER DATABASE testA SET DB_CHAINING ON;  
ALTER DATABASE testB SET DB_CHAINING ON;
```

Grant permission to read from the view.

```
USE [TestB]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[ViewA] TO [TestUser];
GO
```

Login with TestUser into SSMS and run this:

```
USE [TestB]
GO
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ViewA]
USE [TestA]
GO
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[t1]
GO
```

You should see all the rows from testA.dbo.ViewA table via the view but get following error message for the select on table t1.

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 6 The SELECT permission was denied on
>   the object 't1', database 'TestA', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: I would add a note that cross-database ownership chaining is off by default(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669059(v=vs.110).aspx#Off By Default) for security reasons.