# Cannot find the object because it does not exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

I have two databases DB_A and DB_B. From DB_A the developers are calling a stored procedure that will truncate table_a in DB_B. When they execute the stored procedure using the login from the application, we will call this "app_user", it returns the error message. Cannot find object "" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Now my first instinct is to check the permissions for app_user on both DB_A and DB_B. The user is a db_owner on the latter. I ran the sp_change_users_login to see if the database user was orphaned, and it was not. I am not exactly sure why I am still getting this error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the object exist? I.e. does the table or proc that is being called exist? Both need to exist, obviously. Lastly, does app_user the login being used for the linked server, or other connection method to db_2?

Comment: If an "application role" isn't involved, another factor that comes to mind is that it won't hurt to address an object using the schema name, and to square-quote the name parts, i.e. [DB_B].[dbo].[name of table].  Having said...  is the object name shown in the message as "" ?  That rings a bell about "linked server" operations, not quite relevant maybe, but, I think that I HAVE to name a linked server object with [dbo] not .. , AND that I wasn't allowed to truncate a table by four-part naming and/or by sending the Truncate statement to execute at the other end - _except_  in stored procedure.

Comment: Does app_user have permission to truncate that table? Having execute on the stored procedure is NOT enough in this case because ownership chaining doesn't span databases by default. (And enabling cross-database ownership chaining is a security nightmare)

Comment: The object does exist. If I run it with  my login, it works, but I'm a sysadmin. It's not a linked server. The databases are on the same instance.

Comment: @amtwo the user is the db_owner on the database on which the truncate is being executed

Comment: After some debugging, I found I run the contents of the stored procedure directly on _DB_B_, it works with no errors. However, if I run the same script in _DB_A_ fully qualifying the object. e.g. **[DB_B].[Schema].[Object]** I get the error.

Comment: Yes, this is due to the security context not transfering between databases as you are assuming it will. I am writing up an answer on how to easily, and securely, solve this..

Answer (score 1):

This issue here is that it doesn't so much matter what the User in `DB_B` is because Database-level permissions, by default, do not transfer between Databases. There are ways of getting this to work that require little effort, but that are also huge security risks: enabling Cross-Database Ownership Chaining and/or enabling the `TRUSTWORTHY` Database property. But you don't need either of those. Instead, what you can do is:

1. Create a Certificate in `DB_A`
2. Sign the Stored Procedure in `DB_A` with that Certificate
3. Extract the Certificate bytes and Private Key bytes using the built-in functions: [CERTENCODED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/certencoded-transact-sql) and [CERTPRIVATEKEY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/certprivatekey-transact-sql)
4. Create that same Certificate in `DB_B` using the extracted Certificate and Private Key bytes
5. Create a User in `DB_B` from that Certificate
6. Add the Certificate-based User in `DB_B` to the `db_owner` Database Role.

Please see the following answer of mine on a related question that shows this working between two databases:

[Giving Special Permissions to a Stored Procedure in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158609/giving-special-permissions-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server/158640#158640)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this response; however the route to the answer was much simpler. I am almost embarrassed  to even mention what was the error, but if this will help someone else, it is well worth it. Apparently the procedure was being called with a *EXECUTE AS USER = app_user* statement. As mentioned before, the "database users permissions" are not transferable. When run as *EXECUTE AS LOGIN*, it worked. Also when run logged into ssms as the login it works as well. Thank you everyone for your response

Comment: Are you saying that you are using `EXECUTE AS LOGIN=app_user` where app\_user is what the app is logging in as, and what the User in both DB_A and DB_B are created from? Or is it a different Login?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky They were using EXECUTE AS USER = app_user instead of using EXECUTE AS LOGIN = app_user. So, when executing the stored procedure, it was trying to pass the user permission between databases which we know will not happen.

Comment: Right, but my questions are: 1) is the "app_user" in both of those cases the same Login / User? 2) Is it the same Login that the app is already connecting as? 3) if yes to #2, then is it even necessary to use EXECUTE AS since that was already the security context?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky They were trying using the EXECUTE AS because they wanted to see if the script would run with  "app_user".They weren't trying it via the application they were running the code in SSMS first.