# Cross-database view - Not able to access database under the current security context

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, users

We have two databases, `Adb` and `Bdb`. In `Bdb`, we create a view that references another view in `Adb`, like so: `CREATE VIEW Bdb.dbo.Bview AS SELECT * FROM Adb.dbo.Aview`.

We have an SQL Authenticated `Blogin`, mapped to `Buser`, both on `Adb` and `Bdb`, with at least the `db_datareader` role on both.

The following doesn't work:

```
USE Bdb;
EXECUTE AS USER = 'Buser';
SELECT * FROM Bdb.dbo.Bview;
SELECT * FROM Adb.dbo.Aview;
```

The following error is thrown for both selects:

```
Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 4
The server principal "Buser" is not able to access the database "Adb" under the current security context.
```

However, this works:

```
USE Adb;
EXECUTE AS USER = 'Buser';
SELECT * FROM Adb.dbo.Aview;
SELECT * FROM Bdb.dbo.Bview;
```

I have noticed that when I first `USE Bdb` and switch to `Buser`, I can't see any other databases:

```
USE Bdb;
EXECUTE AS USER = 'Buser';
SELECT * FROM sys.databases; -- only master, tempdb and Bdb is shown
```

But, when I `USE Adb` first, I see all of them, even ones that don't have the `Buser` and can't be accessed by it:

```
USE Adb;
EXECUTE AS USER = 'Buser';
SELECT * FROM sys.databases; -- all DBs on the server are shown
```

What could be causing this issue? What should I check?

Comment: Could Bdb be a contained database?  SELECT name, containment_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name IN ('Bdb', 'Adb')

Comment: You are executing in the context of the `user`, try executing instead under the context of the `login` (bearing in mind that they are different and don't have context outside of the current database. I would expect results using `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'Buser';`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First things first: DO NOT ENABLE TRUSTWORTHY!! There is absolutely no reason to open up such a large security hole. (note: `msdb` has `TRUSTWORTHY` enabled and that is fine as it is a Microsoft-supplied DB; User created DBs never *need* `TRUSTWORTHY` enabled)

Now, if this works when impersonating a User instead of a Login, it is due to your `[Adb]` Database already being enabled as `TRUSTWORTHY ON`, which removes the default quarantine that exists when using Database-level Impersonation. You can see this by executing the following:

```
SELECT db.is_trustworthy_on, *
FROM   sys.databases db
WHERE  db.[name] IN (N'Adb', N'Bdb');
```

Assuming that it is the case that `Adb` is enabled for `TRUSTWORTHY` and `Bdb` is not, then still please do not enable `TRUSTWORTHY` for `Bdb`. It would be best to *disable* `TRUSTWORTHY` for `Adb` and use Module Signing to accomplish this:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Adb] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF;
```

For an example of doing this cross-database access via Module Signing, please see the following answer of mine (here on DBA.SE):

[Access view based on table in another database without account in that other database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/193260/30859)

For more info on why you should use Module Signing instead of TRUSTWORTHY (or even Cross-Database Ownership Chaining), please see the following post of mine:

[PLEASE, Please, please Stop Using Impersonation, TRUSTWORTHY, and Cross-DB Ownership Chaining](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/)

For more info on Module Signing in general, please see:

https://ModuleSigning.info/

---

As @Nic mentioned in a comment on the question, it is best to use `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` instead of `EXECUTE AS USER` when testing. Logins are at the Server-level and will have access to Database's that a User has been created in for that Login. This will be just like logging into SQL Server as that account.

The reason for the difference is stated in the Microsoft documentation page for [Extending Database Impersonation by Using EXECUTE AS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304.aspx#Anchor_0)

> **Understanding Impersonation Scope**
>
> ...
>
> However, when impersonating a principal by using the EXECUTE AS USER statement, or within a database-scoped module by using the EXECUTE AS clause, the scope of impersonation is restricted to the database by default. This means that references to objects outside the scope of the database will return an error.

Also, there is a lot of good information on the "Extending Database Impersonation by Using EXECUTE AS" MSDN page (linked above) that explains authenticators and the reasoning behind these rules.

Given that these two Databases are vendor-supplied (info added after I submitted this answer), then it is probably best to just switch to `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` and *not* make any changes to the Databases (for Module Signing).

Comment: Regarding the first point in more detail: [Guidelines for using the TRUSTWORTHY database setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2183687/guidelines-for-using-the-trustworthy-database-setting-in-sql-server)

Comment: @LowlyDBA Thanks, I will amend my answer to include a note about `msdb`. But outside of Microsoft supplied databases, there is never a good / valid reason to enable `TRUSTWORTHY`. Also, I have added a link to a post I just published which is a write-up of a presentation I give on what the reasoning is behind this :-), in more detail than MS has ever provided ;-)

Comment: Sweet site! Definitely adding to my bookmark list.

Comment: So this whole time, the problem was `EXECUTE AS USER` instead of `LOGIN`? Damn. These are both vendor supplied DBs on our servers, the `B` application needs access to some data of the `A` application, which is why we created some views - to only allow access to what is required. I don't know the actual password of the `Buser`, which is why I've been using `EXECUTE AS` to test access. With `EXECUTE AS LOGIN`, everything works. Thanks for all the info about the other topics as well!

Comment: @SolomonRutzky even you add `Buser` login as user in both DB it will not work on `Bdb` database because `EXECUTE AS USER` cannot read from `Adb` (nested view). As @Nic mentioned `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` will work in this case not because of best practice but login will be able to get access to `Adb`.

Comment: @ROAL I have updated my answer. Please review. Also, in the future, it helps to put info such as "these are vendor-supplied DBs" into the question :-).

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I realized that after I had added the testing for `TRUSTWORTHY` part but forgot to remove the top section. I have updated the answer to remove the incorrect info and added more explanation. Also, I've done additional testing and have integrated the info into the "PLEASE, Please, please...." blog post linked in the answer.

Comment: same here, `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is Bdb a trusted Database?

```
SELECT name, is_trustworthy_on FROM sys.databases
```

To use EXECUTE AS to another DB you need to set up trust between the Databases:

```
ALTER DATABASE Bdb SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
GO
```

However there is a lot of security concerns around doing this, only do this if you actually understand the risks.

You can read more here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304(v=sql.105).aspx
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2183687/guidelines-for-using-the-trustworthy-database-setting-in-sql-server